# Why does the screensize affect the velocity of a node?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my game, I apply an impulse to a spritnode, it works fine in the **iPhone 6 simulator**, but in the **iPad simulator**, it doesn't jump high enough and in the **iPhone 4S** and **5S simulator**, it jumps too high?

This is what I do

```
[player.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0,60)];
```

How can I make the spritenode jump the same height on all devices?

Comment: I think its something to do with the number of points on a screen and how you lay out your target jump height. Say your target is a platform or something set in the middle of the screen, the distance from the "ground" to the platform is going to be larger on an iPad than on an iPhone, so the hardcoded impulse of 60 isn't always going to work. I believe using an impulse calculated from screen height would help you out with this?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it like that